# cakebuild: How to specify license in DotNetCorePack?

Tags: nuget, cakebuild

I try to specify the license for a nuget package in a cake script.

The following does not work - it doesn't put any license in the nuget package, and I can't find any documentation how to properly specify it:

```
   var msbuildsettings = new DotNetCoreMSBuildSettings();
   msbuildsettings = msbuildsettings.WithProperty("PackageLicenseExpression", "'LGPL-2.0-or-later'");

   var settings = new DotNetCorePackSettings
    {
        MSBuildSettings = msbuildsettings,
        Configuration = "Release",
        OutputDirectory = "BuildOutput/NugetPackages",
        NoBuild = true,

    };

    foreach(var gassembly in list)
        DotNetCorePack(gassembly.Csproj, settings);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is a Cake issue.  Cake just wraps existing tools.

The NuGet docs tell you how to specify package meta data.  You generally want to specify metadata in the csproj when using `dotnet pack`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `PackageLicenseExpression` property should be a valid [SPDX license identifier](https://spdx.org/licenses/) string without any apostrophes.

Just remove the apostrophes and your code should work fine and add the license expression to the NuGet package.

```
msbuildsettings = msbuildsettings.WithProperty("PackageLicenseExpression", "LGPL-2.0-or-later");
```